# jasmine: Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.. When i am trying get a non present element

Tags: protractor

When I am trying to check presence of not presented element/ button.  I am getting:

> Jasmine timeout exception

My code like

```
getName(): any {
    let name = element(by.id("xxxxxx"));
    return name.isPresent().then((ispresent) => {
        if (ispresent) {
            return name.getText();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to access that method `expect(method).toequal('');`

It should run, because if not present i am expecting empty string but i am getting Jasmine timeout.. I didn't added any waits any where.

Answer (score 1):

#### [isPresent()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts#L434)

From the GitHub repo, `ElementFinder.isPresent`

```
isPresent(): wdpromise.Promise<boolean> {
  return this.count().then((count) => {
    return count > 0;
  });
}
```

isPresent checks for a count, but does not catch if there is an error. If the count throws, we should probably return 0. Getting a text for an element that does not exist should also have throw a promise rejection.

Note: It might be better to change your method to async / await (optional).

```
async getName(): webdriver.promise.Promise<string> {
  const name = element(by.id("xxxxxx"));
  try {
    return name.getText();
  } catch (e) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Or not async / await

```
getName(): webdriver.promise.Promise<string> {
  const name = element(by.id("xxxxxx"));
  return name.getText().catch(e) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
async getName() {
    let name = element(by.id("xxxxxx"));
    let value: string = '';
    await name.ispresent().then((ispresent) => {
        if (ispresent) {
            value=name.getText();
        } 
    });
   return value;
}
```

Hope it helps you